# Open.window in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, window.open

I am making a simple webpage for fun and I am a noob at JavaScript and I want to make 
windows open up when clicked and I want to open them up inside an iframe and I want to give it all the functionality of a normal window.open and I also want it to maximize the windows but inside the iframe and not outside. I know About the window.open and go it to work I just want to make the windows work inside an iframe and not outside. I am using Notepad for as my editor.  This is my first question so please forgive me if I made any mistakes thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't really understand... Oh and also: https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6928617728/hA937289F/

Comment: @DumbProducts http://jsfiddle.net/SHEj9/

Comment: You can't 'maximize' the window (I assume you meant that the page should fill/fit the iframe) inside an iframe because that depends on the page that is loaded and not you.

Comment: You can not do what you want to do with window.open.

Answer (score 43):

#### If you want to open a `window` within an `iframe`:

1. Create the `iframe` with a name.

   ```
    <iframe name="theFrame"></iframe>
   ```
2. Now use the `script` this way:

   ```
    window.open(url, "theFrame");
   ```

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't work. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script> function openWin() { myWindow=window.open(http://www.bing.com,'','width=200,height=100,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes',); myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>"); myWindow.focus(); } </script> </head> <body> </iframe> <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" "theFrame" /> </body> </html> This is my current code I want to make it so that I can make it open inside an iframe like a window or another iframe an then I can drag it, resize it, maximize/minimize it, and close it.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: url is not defined

Comment: @Joyston You haven't defined `url`.

Comment: What should be the url if I just wat to open the ifrane in a blank window @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Joyston The `url` should be the URL of the window to be opened.

Comment: @PraveenKumar _blank?

Answer (score 2):

If you give your iFrame a name attribute, you can reference that name in the target attribute of your links.

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="IFrame">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: I am trying to get windows opened up inside an iframe so that when I do the javascript attribute window.open I can move them, resize, them, and maximize/minimize them inside the iframe.

Comment: So, you want an entire browser window inside of the iframe?

Comment: Yes, I pretty much want an entire browser windows inside the iframe is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, you can show the entire content of a webpage within an iframe, but  you cannot display an address bar, forward, back, or other controls like a browser *inside* of the iframe. You could possibly use the resizable property of css3 to be able to allow an iframe to be resizable, just like the comment boxes on stack overflow are.

Comment: Thanks a lot also is there a way I can drag and move my iframe

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. From http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask