# place an iframe using javascript in php in a block of magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, iframe

I have the following code in a magento block:

```
class Dc_Decidir_Block_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setAction(Mage::helper('decidir')->getPaymentGatewayUrl())
            ->setId('decidir_checkout')
            ->setName('decidir_form')
            ->setMethod('get')
            ->setUseContainer(true);

        $decidir = Mage::getModel('decidir/decidir');
        foreach ($decidir->getCheckoutFormFields() as $field => $value) 
        {
            $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name' => $field, 'value' => $value));
            Mage::helper('decidir')->log('Form Field: ' . $field);
            Mage::helper('decidir')->log('Form Value: ' . $value);
        }

        $html = $this->__('Serás redirigido(a) al Botón de Pagos');
        $html.= $form->toHtml();
        $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("decidir_checkout").submit();</script>';


        return $html;
    }
}
```

this function is redirected to a url that takes out by means of an existing form.
example: www.example.com?name=tito&number=05&id=09485

It works very well but they ask me to have this redirection inside an iframe.

Is it possible to modify the java code so that it loads the url in an iframe? or any idea of how to do it?

tks!

Comment: What do you mean by "but they ask me"?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML/JS involved, I can't give a full answer, but perhaps you can accomplish this goal by using an iframe for the `target` attribute of either the link/button you are using or the script.  Either way, the iframe would have to be pre-existing and have a `name` attribute assigned.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/3gsdm4uL/5/) with an example in pure HTML example.

Here is an [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105021/5517065) that explains how to do it with JS with a `window.open()` function.

Comment: there is no html involved, because MAGENTO stores and loads what the script returns $ html = http://www.elsitio.com/ (inside the block).
The query was that instead of being loaded directly into the window, the same link that resolves the script is loaded into an iframe.