# How to open a page in iframe?

Tags: html, cookies, iframe

Insert a link to our application in an iframe.

Format:

```
<iframe src="https://test.test.com"></iframe>
```

When opened in a browser instead of a page it returns:

```
<html><script>window.location.href=window.location.href</script><html>
```

The problem is unstable. For some users a page opens. If you blocked cookie in the browser the page also opens.Changed dns and nginx settings. Not affected. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know if you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104801/open-window-in-iframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open.window in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104801/open-window-in-iframe)