# A button on being clicked should open a webpage in an iframe named destination

Tags: html, css, button, onclick

I have written the following code and the button which is being clicked opens a webpage in a new window. I want the button to open the webpage in an iframe named "destination". The code is as follows

```
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('index1.php')" target="destination">3-2</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('index2.php')" target="destination">4-1</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
```

Comment: You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105021/14170294).

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open an iFrame directly because an Iframe is to display a window within another web page. So you will have to link to a web page that contains that iFrame window.

However you make use of a web page that includes all iFrame options like:

```
if request(i) = "1" {$frame = "content1.php;)
else if request(i) = "2" {$frame = "content2.php;}
else if request(i) = "3" {$frame = "content3.php;}
```

And then write in your iFrame like:

```
 <iframe src="<?php echo $frame; ?>"></iframe>
```

Then link to your iFrame using something like
http://example.com/page.php?i=2